# Objective c - Regular expression to find multiple words

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am struggling to write a regular expression(Objective C) to match a javascript function. The function has plenty of code in it but what sets it aside from other functions in the document is that it is the only function that calls split, join, slice and reverse.

```
function aa(b)
{
   split()
   join()
   slice()
   reverse()
}
```

I need to write a regular expression to match this function. Here is what I have:

```
// WORKS but matches many other functions. 
 NSString *functions = @"function\\s\\w{2,2}\\(\\w{1,1}\\)\\{(.*)\\}";

// DOES NOT WORK 
 NSString *functions = @"function\\s\\w{2,2}\\(\\w{1,1}\\)\\{(.*)split()(.*)join(.*)slice(.*)reverse(.*)\\}";
```

I simply need to find a function that has split, join, slice and reverse within its brackets and can't get it working.

EDIT: functions join, split, slice, reserve can action be in different order. So I simply need to detect that they are found between curly brackets of parent function {}. But their order can be different.

I tried using look arounds but does not help:

```
.*\b(slice|split|join)\b.*
```

also tried like this:

```
 (?=.*?\slice\b)(?=.*?\bsplit\b)(?=.*?\bjoin\b).*
```

Can you advice?

Comment: Are you looking for them in that exact order, or fuzzily?  Can there be more calls within the function, or are you looking for functions composed of those 4 calls alone?  `function\\s*\\w{2}\(\\w{1}\\)\\s*{\\s*split\\(\\)\\s*join\\(\\)\\s*slice\\(\\)\\s*reverse\\(\\)\\s*}$` makes the second example work strictly for all functions with two letter names accepting a single param and invoking those four in exact order.

Comment: @CodaFi thank you for your comment. Yes, these functions split, join, slice can be called in different order. I simply need to detect that they present between parent function brackets {}... their order can be different